# How can I stop my program from executing the next statement if the user inputs a specific number?

Tags: java

This program prompts the user to enter an odd integer that will decide the height of a specific diamond pattern. My program executes the other statements even though the user inputs one of the other number listed.

```
if ((number% 2 == 0)|| number <=0 )System.out.println("--- The number you entered is not odd positive!! Please try again!");

 else
    {if (number == 9)

        for (int row = 1 ; row < 10 ; row += 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 10 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println("");
                }

                for (int row = 7 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 9 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println(""); }
                        System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);

     //-----------------------------------------------------------------------

       if (number==7)

                for (int row = 1 ; row < 8 ; row += 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 8 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println("");
                }

                for (int row = 5 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 7 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println("");}
                        System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);
     //---------------------------------------------------------------------------

       if (number == 5)     

               for (int row = 1 ; row < 6 ; row += 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 6 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println("");
                }

                for (int row = 3 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 5 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println("");}
                        System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);
     //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

      if (number == 3)

               for (int row = 1 ; row < 4 ; row += 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 4 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println("");
                }

                for (int row = 1 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                    for (int col = 0 ; col < 3 - row / 2 ; col++)
                        System.out.print(" ");

                    for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                        System.out.print("*");
                        System.out.println("");}
                        System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);}
```

Comment: Your code sample seems incomplete. From glancing over it one possible cause might be that your if statements do not specify a specific scope, which means that if the condition is true the following `for` statement is executed and then the next `for` statement, if not, only the second. What exactly doe you mean with 'other number'?

Comment: @Oban please review and edit your question and make the code more clear, all those for loops have nothing to do with the logic but make noise when reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with your coding style. You are not using **{** after your **if** conditions, therefore only the next statement is related to the **if** condition. I suppose the user only can input a single number, therefore you should use **else if** conditions instead just other **if**.

It would be better if you post the entire method, instead of just a part of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add "break;" or "continue;" at the bottom of each option depending on if you want to break out of or continue through the options.

Also consider using a Switch case statement (Code supplied below is untested and just an example).

I don't know if this is suitable for your needs but it seems you have a simple list of numbers which get selected - switches work great for those situations.
i.e:

pickANumber = sc.nextInt();

```
        switch (pickANumber) { 
           case 3: 
                for (int row = 1 ; row < 4 ; row += 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 4 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println("");
            }

                for (int row = 1 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 3 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println("");}
                    System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);}
              break;

           case 5: 
           for (int row = 1 ; row < 6 ; row += 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 6 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println("");
            }

            for (int row = 3 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 5 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println("");}
                    System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);
              break;

           case 7: 
           for (int row = 1 ; row < 8 ; row += 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 8 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println("");
            }

            for (int row = 5 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 7 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println("");}
                    System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);
              break;

           case 9:
           for (int row = 1 ; row < 10 ; row += 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 10 - 1 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println("");
            }

            for (int row = 7 ; row > 0 ; row -= 2) {
                for (int col = 0 ; col < 9 - row / 2 ; col++)
                    System.out.print(" ");

                for (int col = 0 ; col < row ; col++)
                    System.out.print("*");
                    System.out.println(""); }
                    System.out.println("Here is the diamond shape, whose height is " + number);
                break;

             default: System.out.println("Invalid option entered - please try again");
```